# Dropdown menu with transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

After a long time coding in javascript, I wanted to try doing a beautiful website without **any** javascript (and without jQuery of course). I wanted to do a dropdown menu with tabs like this website : [dropdown tabs](http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw) . But this one is in javascript. I did that : http://jsfiddle.net/jHeRm/. But when I added the transition, I had a problem : the transition is from a point to another, and I can't know the begining point without calculations (height of a `li` * the number of `li`).

How can I do this transition in any way, but without jQuery, javascript, php, IDs and classes?

**EDIT :** I thought of a way to do it by making the transition from `bottom:0px` to `top:21px` but the transition always start from `top:0px` to `top:21px`

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS and animate the height of the nested `ul`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jHeRm/2/

---

Below is an updated version using negative margins:

http://jsfiddle.net/jHeRm/4/

Comment: It could have work but you wrote in the css 66px and this value work only if there is three `li`.

Comment: I want a dropdown with transition, and if you add a transition to that, it will add a delay for 34px (100 - 66). Because here you must specify the top so when the transition begin it immediately go down

Comment: There is only so much u can do with certain tools. I think you're asking for too much out of CSS alone.